# How do I properly specify anchoring conditions in Spirit X3?

Tags: c++, parsing, c++14, boost-spirit, boost-spirit-x3

I am new to writing parsers.  I am attempting to create a parser which can extract US zip codes from input text.  I have created the following parser patterns, which do most of what I want.  I am able to match 5 digit zip codes, or 9 digit zip codes (90210-1234) as expected.

However, it does not allow me to avoid matching things like:

> 246764 (returns 46764)
>   578397 (returns 78397)

I wanted to specify some anchoring conditions for the right and left of the above pattern, in the hopes that I could eliminate the examples above.  More specifically, I want to prohibit matching when digits or dashes are adjacent to the beginning or end of the candidate zip code.

Test data (**bold** entries should be matched)

> **12345**
>
> foo456
>
> ba58r
>
> 246764anc
>
> 578397
>
> 90210-
>   15206-1
>   **15222-1825**
>   15212-4267-53410-2807

Full code:

```
using It = std::string::const_iterator;
using ZipCode = boost::fusion::vector<It, It>;

namespace boost { namespace spirit { namespace x3 { namespace traits {
    template <>
    void move_to<It, ZipCode>(It b, It e, ZipCode& z)
    {
        z =
        {
            b,
            e
        };
}}}}}

void Parse(std::string const& input)
{
    auto start = std::begin(input);
    auto begin = start;
    auto end = std::end(input);

    ZipCode current;
    std::vector<ZipCode> matches;

    auto const fiveDigits = boost::spirit::x3::repeat(5)[boost::spirit::x3::digit];
    auto const fourDigits = boost::spirit::x3::repeat(4)[boost::spirit::x3::digit];
    auto const dash = boost::spirit::x3::char_('-');
    auto const notDashOrDigit = boost::spirit::x3::char_ - (dash | boost::spirit::x3::digit);

    auto const zipCode59 = 
        boost::spirit::x3::lexeme
        [
            -(&notDashOrDigit) >> 
            boost::spirit::x3::raw[fiveDigits >> -(dash >> fourDigits)] >> 
            &notDashOrDigit
        ];

    while (begin != end)
    {
        if (!boost::spirit::x3::phrase_parse(begin, end, zipCode59, boost::spirit::x3::blank, current))
        {
            ++begin;
        }
        else
        {
            auto startOffset = std::distance(start, boost::fusion::at_c<0>(current));
            auto endOffset = std::distance(start, boost::fusion::at_c<1>(current));
            auto length = std::distance(boost::fusion::at_c<0>(current), boost::fusion::at_c<1>(current));
            std::cout << "Matched (\"" << startOffset
                << "\", \"" 
                << endOffset
                << "\") => \""
                << input.substr(startOffset, length)
                << "\""
                << std::endl;
        }
    }
}
```

This code with the above test data produces the following output:

> Matched ("0", "5") => "12345"
>   Matched ("29", "34") => "46764"
>   Matched ("42", "47") => "78397"
>   Matched ("68", "78") => "15222-1825"

If I change zipCode59 to the following, I get no hits back:

```
auto const zipCode59 = 
    boost::spirit::x3::lexeme
    [
        &notDashOrDigit >> 
        boost::spirit::x3::raw[fiveDigits >> -(dash >> fourDigits)] >> 
        &notDashOrDigit
    ];
```

I have read through this question: [Stop X3 symbols from matching substrings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33725521/stop-x3-symbols-from-matching-substrings) .  However, this question makes use of a symbol table.  I don't think this can work for me, because I lack the ability to specify hard-coded strings.  I'm also unclear as to how the answer to that question manages to prohibit the leading content.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `-(parser)` just makes `(parser)` optional. Using it with `-(&parser)` has literally no effect.

Perhaps you wanted a negative assertion ("lookahead"), which is `!(parser)` (the opposite of `&(parser)`).

> Note that the potential confusion maybe because of the difference between unary minus (negative assertion) and binary minus (reducing character sets).

Asserting that a zip-code start with not a dash/digit seems ... confused. If you want to positively assert something else than a dash or digit would be `&~char_("-0-9")` (using unary `~` to negate the character set) but it would prevent matching at the very start of input.

### Positive approach

Shedding some of the complexity left and right I'd naively start out with something like:

```
using It = std::string::const_iterator;
using ZipCode = boost::iterator_range<It>;

auto Parse(std::string const& input) {
    using namespace boost::spirit::x3;
    auto dig = [](int n) { return repeat(n)[digit]; };
    auto const zip59 = dig(5) >> -('-' >> dig(4));
    auto const valid = zip59 >> !graph;

    std::vector<ZipCode> matches;
    if (!parse(begin(input), end(input), *seek[raw[valid]], matches))
        throw std::runtime_error("parser failure");

    return matches;
}
```

Which of course matches too much:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d156bdb0c7fcb561)</kbd>**

```
Matched '12345'
Matched '78397'
Matched '15222-1825'
Matched '53410-2807'
```

### Doing The Heroics

To limit it (and still match at start-of-input) you could `seek[&('-'|digit)]` and then *require* a valid zip.

I freely admit to having had to fiddle with things a bit before getting it "right". In the process I created a debug helper:

```
auto trace_as = [&input](std::string const& caption, auto parser) { 
    return raw[parser] [([=,&input](auto& ctx) { 
        std::cout << std::setw(12) << (caption+":") << " '";
        auto range = _attr(ctx);
        for (auto ch : range) switch (ch) {
            case '\0': std::cout << "\\0"; break;
            case '\r': std::cout << "\\r"; break;
            case '\n': std::cout << "\\n"; break;
            default: std::cout << ch;
        }
        std::cout << "' at " << std::distance(input.begin(), range.begin()) << "\n";
    })]; 
};

auto const valid = seek[&trace_as("seek", '-' | digit)] >> raw[zip59] >> !graph;

std::vector<ZipCode> matches;
if (!parse(begin(input), end(input), -valid % trace_as("skip", *graph >> +space), matches))
    throw std::runtime_error("parser failure");
```

Which produces the following additional diagnostic output:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1f7e73c30e7d88fc)</kbd>**

```
       seek: '1' at 0
       skip: '\n    ' at 5
       seek: '4' at 13
       skip: 'foo456\n    ' at 10
       seek: '5' at 23
       skip: 'ba58r\n    ' at 21
       seek: '2' at 31
       skip: '246764anc\n    ' at 31
       seek: '5' at 45
       skip: '578397\n    ' at 45
       seek: '9' at 56
       skip: '90210-\n    ' at 56
       seek: '1' at 67
       skip: '15206-1\n    ' at 67
       seek: '1' at 79
       skip: '\n    ' at 89
       seek: '1' at 94
Matched '12345'
Matched '15222-1825'
```

Now that the output is what we desire, let's cut the scaffolding again:

### Full Listing

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2c3a93eb557ed5f5)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/spirit/home/x3.hpp>

using It = std::string::const_iterator;
using ZipCode = boost::iterator_range<It>;

auto Parse(std::string const& input) {
    using namespace boost::spirit::x3;
    auto dig = [](int n) { return repeat(n)[digit]; };
    auto const zip59 = dig(5) >> -('-' >> dig(4));
    auto const valid = seek[&('-' | digit)] >> raw[zip59] >> !graph;

    std::vector<ZipCode> matches;
    if (!parse(begin(input), end(input), -valid % (*graph >> +space), matches))
        throw std::runtime_error("parser failure");

    return matches;
}

#include <iostream>
int main() {
    std::string const sample = R"(12345
foo456
ba58r
246764anc
578397
90210-
15206-1
15222-1825
15212-4267-53410-2807)";

    for (auto zip : Parse(sample))
        std::cout << "Matched '" << zip << "'\n";
}
```

Prints:

```
Matched '12345'
Matched '15222-1825'
```

Comment: Simplified [the `trace_as` facility](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1f7e73c30e7d88fc).

Comment: Wow, @sehe, thanks!

I have some clarification questions.  

1. The tracing and some testing indicate that I could use -!graph as the leading condition, rather than '-' | digit.  Then the leading and trailing conditions would be identical.  

2. This is not the first example I've seen where lambdas are used as parser params.  I'm not sure I fully understand what all constitutes a 'parser'.  Can you elaborate, or point me to something that does?

Comment: Comment mod timed out...  

1. Do you see any issue with this (1 above)?

Comment: Yes. `graph` is strictly a superset of "-0-9" (and happens to be the inverse of `space`).

Comment: The presence of lambda **in** a parser expression means a _semantic action_ attached to the preceding parser (`p[action]` invokes `action` when `p` matches). In my code though I have "cleverly" used lambdas _just_ to generate the parser expression (allowing code reuse) as well.