# Boost X3 : what is equivalent to Qi keyword parser directive?

Tags: boost, boost-spirit-qi, boost-spirit-x3

I am considering rewritting a parser made in spirit::qi into x3.
I can not find what is equivalent in X3 to the kwd directive used in conjonction with the / operator.

Answer (score 0):

The kwd directive is not a part of Spirit Qi. It's part of the [Spirit Repository](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_83_0/libs/spirit/repository/doc/html/index.html).

The [`operator/` support](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_83_0/libs/spirit/repository/doc/html/spirit_repository/qi_components/operators/keyword_list.html) is also also not part of Qi. As such, you have to expect to write these yourself.

Luckily in X3 that is relatively simple. I have [many examples](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A85371+kw+x3) on this site showing how to make a `kw` or `ikw` parser modifier:

- [Stop X3 symbols from matching substrings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33725521/stop-x3-symbols-from-matching-substrings/33727419#33727419)
- [Combining rules at runtime and returning rules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49722452/combining-rules-at-runtime-and-returning-rules/49722855#49722855)

To actually get the full behavior with optional repeats and attribute binding I think the only realistic way is to make a custom parser type.

Comment: Well, that would suppose that I have to make a custom parser for each case  i use the operator/ ..  , which are indeed a lot of cases.. that does not seem a solution.

Comment: I meant you can write your a parser type that implements this, like... in a repository::x3 namespace. Of course I wouldn't suggest a concrete one for each use. However, (a) that's too much work for a SO answer (b) I would only consider doing this if I had Very Many Usecases(TM) - not like a dozen in a single application. I feel it's probably way easier to support that by procedurally combining some parsers in X3.

Comment: If you can share your self-contained grammar (with relevant test inputs/outputs) I'd be happy to show how I'd probably port that. As examples of procedurally combining things avoiding the need to make the generic keyword-list directives, see e.g. this similar example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45673378/boost-spirit-x3-parse-into-structs/45683933#45683933

Comment: This answer links a few inspirational examples https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49722452/combining-rules-at-runtime-and-returning-rules/49722855#49722855 and also mentions the fact that [writing custom parsers in X3 is a lot simpler than it used to be in Qi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49722452/combining-rules-at-runtime-and-returning-rules/49722855#comment86461547_49722855)