# enable the correct compilation of this Spirit x3 c++project

Tags: c++, boost, c++17, boost-spirit, boost-spirit-x3

I am practicing using Spirit x3 to parse [C language](https://cs.wmich.edu/%7Egupta/teaching/cs4850/sumII06/The%20syntax%20of%20C%20in%20Backus-Naur%20form.htm) and store it in a custom data structure.

But I encountered huge difficulties and still couldn't compile after 5 days.

Most of the errors prompted are incomplete structures and cannot be assigned.

But I carefully checked that there were no incomplete data structures.

For example, the following structure cannot be converted：
[image]

Who accepts this challenge to help modify the code and make it compile。
The code of the git repository can be cloned and modified at will：

[git code](https://github.com/y138828/compilation_failed)

[C language BNF](https://cs.wmich.edu/%7Egupta/teaching/cs4850/sumII06/The%20syntax%20of%20C%20in%20Backus-Naur%20form.htm)

Comment: Please create a [mcve] instead of linking to github and needlessly pasting text as images.

Comment: I accept the challenge. The fact that the code doesn't fit into a SO post tells you something about the chances though. (@Quimby at least it IS self-contained. But I wonder how they get to 700LoC when it doesn't compile sometimes)

Comment: *How to get to 700LoC that doesn't compile:* "Check my work?  Bah!  On to Dalek victory!"  Then Davros enabled the Daleks to be fully autonomous.  The Daleks immediately turned on Davros and exterminated him. The end.

Comment: @sehe I'm glad you took the challenge。 You can ask me for any necessary input。

Comment: Yeah. It's looking like the code is VASTLY incomplete. There are so many AST nodes defaulting to `unused_type` that I'm really confused as to what parts of the AST you expect to be creatable.

Comment: The code and data structure definitions are complete, as there are too many BNFs nested in C language, I am unable to extract a simple instance.namespace .  change [parse{auto const x = x3::rule<x##_class,ast::x>{#x};}] parse{auto const x = x3::rule<x##_class,ast::test::x>{#x};} ,They remove unused_type

Comment: @sehe  【I am practicing using Spirit x3 to parse C language and store it in a custom data structure.】That's my purpose

Comment: Maybe you can do the edit on the git repository. Parsing C is probably not the best way to start learning X3 :)

Comment: @sehe I have updated it, please update the code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But I carefully checked that there were no incomplete data structures.

That's not what the complaints are about. It says "incompatible", not "incomplete". There are things that do not convert.

Using this adhoc CMakeLists.txt

```
project(cc)
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.22.0)
set(BOOST_ROOT /home/sehe/custom/superboost)
find_package(Boost 1.82.0 REQUIRED)

set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER g++-13)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 23)
add_executable(cc main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(cc Boost::boost)
```

After a few cleanup/review commits I ended up with the first propagation related error for

```
auto const init_declarator_def = ((declarator >> '=' >> initializer) | declarator);
```

You can tell from the rule tag in the error message **here**:

> `rule_def.hpp|214 col 5| required from ‘bool parse::parse_rule(boost::spirit::x3::detail::rule_id<`**`init_declarator_class`**`>, Iterator&, const Iterator&, const Context&, boost::spirit::x3::rule<?>::attribute_type&) [with Iterator = const char*; Context = boost::spirit::x3::context<?>; boost::spirit::x3::rule<?>::attribute_type = ast::test::init_declarator]’`

The AST being:

```
struct init_declarator_1 {
    x3::forward_ast<declarator> pre;
    initializer                 last;
};
struct init_declarator : x3::variant<init_declarator_1, x3::forward_ast<declarator>> {
    using base_type::base_type;
    using base_type::operator=;
};
```

I can see how you expect that to match, but Spirit can't:

`/home/sehe/custom/superboost/libs/spirit/include/boost/spirit/home/x3/support/ast/variant.hpp|184 col 17| error: no match for ‘operator=’ (operand types are ‘boost::spirit::x3::variant<ast::test::init_declarator_1, boost::spirit::x3::forward_ast<ast::test::declarator> >::variant_type’ and ‘`**boost::fusion::deque<ast::test::declarator, ast::test::initializer>**`’)`

How can you assign `fusion::deque<...>` to `init_declarator_1`? I know you adapted it, but X3 has no contextual clue what to synthesize. Make the rule explicit:

```
auto const init_declarator_def = ( //
    (x3::rule<struct _, ast::test::init_declarator_1>{"init_declarator_1"} =
         declarator >> '=' >> initializer) //
    | declarator                           //
);
```

Now it compiles, and the next hiccup is in `selection_statement_class`. Rinse and repeat from here.

### Summary

Debug your attribute compatibility. Ideally, start with SMALL subgrammars, only preceed to the higher level productions IFF the lower-level productions all compile and propagate correctly.

You may note that this is a basic tenet of test-driven programming. Really you cannot expect to grind your way through the error novels if you don't limit the scope to look for context.

### BONUS

Note that I tend to use [a type-coercion facility](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=user%3A85371%20as_type&searchOn=3) to make the above easier:

```
namespace {
    template <typename T>
    struct as_type {
        template <typename Expr>
            auto operator[](Expr&& expr) const {
                return x3::rule<struct _, T>{"as"} = x3::as_parser(std::forward<Expr>(expr));
            }
    };

    template <typename T> static const as_type<T> as = {};
}
```

Now you can write the above anonymous rule like

```
auto const init_declarator_def                                           //
    = as<ast::test::init_declarator_1>[declarator >> '=' >> initializer] //
    | declarator;
```

When you go and fix the `selection_statement` please do yourself a favour and stop using inscrutable names like `selection_statement_1`. We are humans, not code generators.

Really what you need is rules like:

```
auto selection_statement = if_statement | switch_statement;

auto if_statement = "id" >> '(' >> expression >> ')' >> statement >> -("else" >> statement);
```

And the AST to match:

```
struct if_statement {
     expression          cond;
     statement           true_branch;
     optional<statement> false_branch;
};
```

PEG grammar isn't BNF. Also, Spirit is an eDSL for parser specification. Your goal is not a machine translation but a maintainable, productive parser generator.

Comment: See the changes I made to arrive at this answer https://github.com/y138828/compilation_failed/pull/1. Note: before you run into it, be aware that you need to parse keyword boundaries: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33725521/stop-x3-symbols-from-matching-substrings/33727419#33727419

Comment: This is exactly the answer I need.【How can you assign fusion::deque<...> to init_declarator_1? I know you adapted it, but X3 has no contextual clue what to synthesize. Make the rule explicit:】

I have been thinking about why it cannot be converted here. I thought it would automatically convert, but I was wrong。After I compile it first, I will try to optimize my code structure according to your suggestions。Thank you again